# How to trigger a mouseup event defined with D3 on a svg element, with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

I have some event `'mouseup'` defined with D3.js that works great. It opens a bootstrap modal when I click some D3 elements (svg>g>g>g>text to be precise).

```
element.on("mouseup", function(d) {
    console.log('mouseup');
    lastNodeClicked = d.name;
    draw_edit_scheme_modal(d);
    $('#edit-scheme-modal').modal('show');
});
```

I would like to trigger this event from jQuery

```
$('.node text:contains('+lastNodeClicked+')').trigger('mouseup');
```

but that doesn't work ; I don't understand why.
I'm pretty sure the selector is right, I tested it.
Is `.trigger('mouseup')` right ?
I also tried `.mouseup()` and `.onmouseup()`

The reason I want to do that is because `draw_edit_scheme_modal(d);` does a lot of things with the data `d` that I don't know how to do from elsewhere than in the mouseup handler.

EDIT: a click event is fine too :-)

Comment: You can't trigger events in SVG in the same way as you can in html. Why not just name the function (instead of having it be anonymous) and call it?

Comment: @robert I guess because the argument (d) is lost ? I don't see how I could trigger the function with the d argument from jquery.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to figure out what that is and pass it.